# В чем ошибка при формировании запроса or like?

Tags: yii2

Вот собственно сам запрос

```
$search = Search::find()->where(['or like', ['name','description'], $query])->limit(30);
```

Вы дает такую ошибку

```
strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

в [документации](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-query-builder.md) описано так

> or like: похож на оператор like, только утверждения LIKE будут
>   объединяться с помощью оператора OR, если второй операнд будет
>   представлен массивом.

Comment: Как я понял первым передается формат операторов, вторым имя поля, третьим - варианты. Соответственно у вас сейчас массив на том месте, где должно указываться имя поля, к которому применяется этот оператор..Ибо к чему его применять сейчас?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$search = Search::find()
->where([
     'OR',
     ['like', 'name', $query],
     ['like', 'description', $query]
])
->limit(30);
```